# How to set the logConfiguration for a job-definition created in AWS batch

Tags: docker, logging, amazon-ecs, terraform-provider-aws, aws-batch

I am using AWS batch to create and run jobs based on a docker image that runs some python code.

Everything is working as expected and I can find the log-output in AWS Cloudwatch.
Now, I would like to add a logging configuration. I would like the log-output to be grouped properly also in cases where one output has multiple lines.

I found in the [AWS-ECS-Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/using_awslogs.html), that one can define `awslogs-multiline-pattern` in the options for the log-configuration for this purpose. However, this only applies for ECS-Taks. I did not find anything about how to achieve the same when creating task definitions in AWS-Batch. Instead it seems that Batch defines some fixed log-configuration that cannot be overwritten.

I am using terraform to define the batch-environment and the job-definitions. I tried to add a `logConfiguration` to the `container_properties` of the `aws_batch_job_definition`, but this was not even recognized as a change. So I guess this might not be supported.

So my main question is: Is there a way to create the Batch job-definitions (or the compute environment) in such a way that the log-configuration works?

I am not sure I understand the relationship between Batch and ECS completely. I can see that creating and running a job in Batch actually creates ECS-Tasks (with some logConfiguration). Maybe some more context would be helpful here: When are those ECS-Tasks created, when are they destroyed and is it an option to manage those from terraform?